# Change credentials on GCloud API Storage manually due to account used is deleted

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage

i would like to ask.
There is a Golang instance running, which has features to upload/download to Google Cloud Storage API. Due to last developer is out and the credentials used is his, now his account is deleted.
Can i change the credentials manually to my account?

Sorry for bad explanation but i will try to give more details if u guys asked.

This is the response which i get if i access Google Cloud Storage API.

```
message: "Post https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/psb/o?alt=json&projection=full&uploadType=multipart: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request↵Response: {↵  "error": "invalid_grant",↵  "error_description": "Account has been deleted"↵}"
```

status: "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: You will need to need to replace the credentials. Start reading [here](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go#hdr-Authentication_and_Authorization) to find out how credentials are supplied to the Google Cloud APIs.

Comment: Your error message is an OAuth error message. How are you logging in to access Cloud Storage? Is this a Google Account (like you would use for Gmail) or a Service Account? If a Service Account, create new service account credentials in the Google Cloud Console (IAM -> Service Accounts), assign rights to the storage bucket and then use the new service account credentials.

Comment: @JohnHanley My prediction it was a credentials that used from gmail account for my company and it has been deactived. Looks like i dont have any option to rebuild the program and uses new credentials using Service Account. Fyi: i dont have the code, it was just running a golang program from local to gcs and receive it from gcs using 'gsutil cp'

Comment: Oauth requires json file of cred to work. Find for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in you enviroment variable. It will be pointing to the location of credentials file used by appliaction. Just replace file there with another credntial having same rights ( permissions ) for gcp